# Unable to Create App package (the .appxupload file) in Visual Studio 2013 for a windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Create App pakages option is disabled..

Cuz i have to upload my app package so as to publish it.. so am stuck with it.
i Have also logind with my developer microsoft account to0.

Edit:
actually in Visual Studio 2013,
in PROJECT > STORE> (all the options available are disabled)... so this the problem.

Comment: Do a clean build.  If that doesn't work then increment the version number the assembly.

Comment: actually in Visual Studio 2013,
in PROJECT > STORE> (all the options available are disabled)... so this the problem.

Comment: Open *Project -> your project properties*, take a look if it's WP application or library.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is Windows Phone 8.1 App, you can create appx package using project -> store in vs.

But if your app is Windows Phone 8 App or Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 App, you don't need to create appx file, the only file you need is xap file in Bin/Release(or Debug) folder. When you publish it, just upload your xap file is OK.

Comment: but in dev-center whenn i upload .xap file
it says
You can upload only .appx, .appxbundle or .appxupload files.

Comment: did you in https://dev.windowsphone.com (For WP)or https://appdev.microsoft.com/(For Windows Store), you should submit your wp app to WP store.

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me, and (after 20 minutes of VS restarts), I realized the **Project** needs to be selected instead of the Solution at the Solution Explorer.

This way all Store options are enabled again.